# Rational Function is Square of Modulus of Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In problem 14.5 of papa Rudin, it is asking if $f(t)=\sum_{k=-n}^n a_ke^{ikt}$ and we have $f(t)>0$ for $t$ is real number, then we have $f(t)=|P(e^{it})|^2$ for some polynomial $P$ of degree $n$. I did this by showing that
\begin{align*}
f(t)=c\prod_{k=1}^n (e^{it}-\alpha_k)(e^{-it}-\overline{\alpha_k})
\end{align*}
for some $c>0$. Now if we only have $f(t)\geq 0$, can this argument still work? My doubt is we can have $c=0$ if we use this argument so we don't get what we want.

Comment: If $c=0$ the function is the zero function, that means that $a_k=0$ for each $k$. That means that 
$f(t)$ is the empty sum. So $f(t)$ need to be expressed by a degree $0$ polynomial (or $-\infty$, depending on which convenction you use for the degree of the $0$ polynomial). That is actually the case

Comment: @Marco thank you.